# Работа с SVG и CSS

Tags: css, svg, path, transform

**Вопрос номер 1:** Анимация для **`path`** через файл **.css** не работает, а напрямую вместе с тегом работает. Почему? Или почему может не работать?

**Вопрос номер 2:** Нужно по событию **`:hover`** для **`svg`** элемента поменять цвета для **`path`** элементов, но суть в том, что для первого элемента рамку сделать зелёной, а фон былый. А для второго рамку и фон сделать зелёного цвета. Как это сделать? Можно ли так сделать?

```css
svg {
  background: #DCDCDC;
}

.line {
  stroke: grey;
  fill: grey;
}

.page {
  stroke: grey;
  fill: white;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

.Red {
  stroke: white;
  fill: red;
}

.Red:hover {
  transform: rotate(10);
}

.Blue {
  stroke: white;
  fill: blue;
}

.Green {
  stroke: white;
  fill: green;
}

.Black {
  stroke: white;
  fill: black;
}

svg:hover>.page,
svg:hover>.line {
  stroke: green;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <path class="page" d="M 60 10 V 150 H 160 V 10 Z"/>
  <path class="line" d="M 70 50 V 60 H 150 V 50 Z M 70 70 V 80 H 150 V 70 Z M 70 90 V 100 H 150 V 90 Z"/>
  <path class="page" d="M 40 30 V 170 H 140 V 30 Z"/>
  <path class="line" d="M 50 70 V 80 H 130 V 70 Z M 50 90 V 100 H 130 V 90 Z M 50 110 V 120 H 130 V 110 Z"/>
  <path class="page" d="M 20 50 V 190 H 120 V 50 Z"/>
  <path class="line" d="M 30 90 V 100 H 110 V 90 Z M 30 110 V 120 H 110 V 110 Z M 30 130 V 140 H 110 V 130 Z"/>
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <path class="Black" d="M 25 40 L 45 40 L 45 60 L 25 60 Z"/>
  <path class="Green" d="M 20 50 L 25 40 L 25 60 L 20 70 Z"/>
  <path class="Black" d="M 25 60 L 45 60 L 40 70 L 20 70 Z"/>
  <path class="Red" d="M 20 50 L 40 50 L 40 70 L 20 70 Z"/>
  <path class="Blue" d="M 25 40 L 45 40 L 40 50 L 20 50 Z"/>
  <path class="Black" d="M 40 50 L 45 40 L 45 60 L 40 70 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Браузер: ***IE 11***

Comment: Если просто поставить без hover тоже не работает, а вообще это как так нету hover, если в первом случае я меняю цвета по svg:hover

Comment: Чего? Что должно произойти? И причем тут Хром?

Comment: О Браузер: IE 11

Comment: Как это всё относится к моим вопросам?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский.**вопрос очень актуальный - но то что IE11 не поддерживает path тоже верно ... вопрос хоть и полезный но без полезный так как решающий ответ на него один path не поддерживается в ie11**                                             Это как не поддерживается, если я на IE11 и пишу?

Comment: Бессмысленно то, что у вас нет никаких уточнений по поводу "path не поддерживается IE11 ", как так, если все работает. О чём именно вы говорите я не понимаю. Уточните пожайлуста.

Comment: А вы уверены, что она рабочая? Сами проверяли? Просто у меня все работает, хотя там написано, что не должно :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33828560/6339052  это о чём то говорит ?

Comment: =) Не работает path анимация, а не path. Спасибо за ссылку, а как на счет второго вопроса? Знаете как сделать?

Comment: за фон в svg отвечает `fill` за цвет рамки `stroke` за толщину рамки `stroke-width` , `hover` замените на `onmouseout`  [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events) подробно

Comment: А через css нельзя? С hover, мож способ какой есть? Через javascript сделать сделал, но IE постоянно требует включить скрипт. Знаете как обойти? Про обойти я имею ввиду, что не надо в настройках отключать ничего, а чтобы у всех принимала javascript как безопасный код.